# magento how to translate "browse files..."? (uploader.swf)

Tags: flash, apache-flex, magento, translation

if I understand correctly, the "browse files..." and "upload files..." buttons shown at the back office to upload pictures cannot be translated!!

it's a flash component (swf)
We need to recompile it.

First I have updated uploader.mxml with the FRENCH translation.
Second I downloaded flex and ran this command:

`mxmlc uploader.mxml -compiler.source-path C:\wamp\www\magento\lib\flex\varien -compiler.source-path C:\flex\frameworks\javascript\fabridge\src\`

But I got error linked to some styles like borderColor, gradianAlpha.
It says something like it can only work with the theme "halo"!
No idea what does it mean...

I removed those settings from the XML file and I was able to generate a SWF.
But the color are not visible now :-(

Any idea how to solve this?
Or anyone having it in french?

thanks,
Rod

Answer (score 0):

actually I removed the style that was not compatible with Flex 4.
And I use chromeColor="0xFC8227" to set the background color.
Now it works